# Reputation deducted

Tags: support, reputation

Suddenly today 2 upvote reputation deducted. As in the image you can see last 2 entries. Can any help me know why this happened?

This is that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546170/jquery-selectors-what-is-wrong-with-my-code/17546274#17546274) which I am talking about.

[image]

Comment: Moral: don't check a box if you don't know what it means. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I thought it will useful to others who are in learning phase, but the concept of wiki was somewhat different as I understood it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the answer is a community wiki, you do not receive rep for votes on community wikis.

If you edit the answer there should be a checkbox right under the edit box that says "community wiki". Uncheck that box and you will get rep for the answer. I don't know if it is will give you the rep that you should have gained though, or only the new upvote rep.

Comment: Can any moderator remove it from community wiki? As I misunderstood the concept of community wiki. :( As the answer is complete and doesn't requires any more changes in that question

Comment: I'm not sure. I've never used the community wiki checkbox. I think you can edit it since it is your answer and undo that checkbox, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: You can't undo community wiki, a moderator needs to do it (and they decide whether to undo it on a case-by-case basis I think).

Comment: @ChiragVidani - I went ahead and removed the community wiki status on that answer for you.

Comment: @TronicZomB I thought it will useful to others who are in learning phase, but the concept of wiki was somewhat different as I understood it

Comment: @BradLarson Does upvote rollback when question is removed from community wiki?